# Where do I find 'App Service Logs' settings?

Tags: azure-functions

I created a precompiled C# Azure Function and deployed it to Azure. It's working as designed.

In the Azure Portal, I'm going through the settings / options for managing my function app . I clicked the banner "Preview the new Azure Functions management experience". The UI switched to the new blade-style UI for Azure Functions.

When I clicked `Log stream` under `Monitoring`, a message appeared `Application logs are switched off. You can turn them on using the 'App Service logs' settings.` Where do I turn on the application logs?

If I access the `Log stream` using the current UI - not the new UI in preview - and then switch to the preview UI, the Log stream console window is displayed - the previous message no longer appears - and the log messages flow as expected. This doesn't answer the question but it did help me finish the task I was initially working on.

Comment: Application logs is already turn on, this seams a bug.

Comment: I try to create some new azure function app, and get the same thing. As long as you have create timetrigger in the Azure Function before, the problem will disappear even if you have delete the timetrigger.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to look for 'App Service Logs' settings. Azure function cannot choose this setting. Application logs should be turned on by default in Azure function.

This is what you face now:

[image]

Go to Preview the new Azure Functions management experience and i get this problem. At the same time, directly click log stream under Platform features works well.

It says Application logs are switched off. You can turn them on using the 'App Service logs' settings, but i dont think so. The application logs have already on.

Because if you create a timetrigger in your function app, the problem will disappear. Then even if you delete the timetrigger, the problem will not happened again.(The reason I found this problem was because I had two Function App, one reproduced your problem, and the other performed well. The only difference between them is that the latter has timetrigger.)

This should be a bug, the application logs is been turn on.(As you says, using the current UI is no problem.)